# access aspx page in application root from a page in subfolder

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have the following directory structure.

Snowball

--  User

-----   UserControl

I have a page ShoppingCart.aspx under User and it has a static property CartType.Now inside that userControl folder I have a user control OrderSummary.ascx.I want to access CartType property from this user control.

I can only access classes that are inside this UserControl folder.How to acess CartType property

Answer (score 0):

Import the namespace of the ShoppingCart class into your UserControl.  If you're trying to access it in the markup, use this at the top of your page:

```
<%@ Import namespace="Snowball.User" %>
```

If you're doing it in codebehind, just import the namespace like usual with a "using" statement (C#) or "Imports" (VB) at the top of the codebehind file.

Comment: I do not have any namespace defined.I simply have partial classes.In that case how can i use using statement.